# Adding new ciphers to ssh2-stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, ssh

Im trying to connect to a ssh server with the 'ssh2' module but the server ciphers' not match any of chipers on the ssh2-stream ciphers.
here is ssh-session logs:

```
+LiveParser:DEBUG: Outgoing: Writing DISCONNECT (KEY_EXCHANGE_FAILED)

+LiveParser:DEBUG: No matching Client->Server cipher

+LiveParser:DEBUG: (remote) Client->Server ciphers: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc

+LiveParser:DEBUG: (local) Client->Server ciphers: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
```

how could add those cipher to my app??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation for `connect()`](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/#client-methods) shows all of the possible connection options. One of them (new in `ssh2` v0.5) is the `algorithms` option. You can explicitly set the list of ciphers to use during algorithm negotiation like so:

```
conn.connect({
  // ...
  algorithms: {
    cipher: [
      'aes128-ctr',
      'aes192-ctr',
      'aes256-ctr',
      'aes128-gcm',
      'aes128-gcm@openssh.com',
      'aes256-gcm',
      'aes256-gcm@openssh.com',
      'aes256-cbc'
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: what about ciphers algorithms??is it enough to just mentioning their names??

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The example I show is how you override the default list of ciphers to use when connecting to the server. In my particular example, I merely took the default list and appended one of the better ciphers supported by the server in your question. This tries to match a better cipher first and fall back to `aes256-cbc` if necessary.

Comment: here is the supported list of cipher algorithms of 'ssh2-stream'  module:
aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
As u see 'aes256-cbc' not supported. I'm asking how to add algorithm of this cipher to 'ssh2-module'. just opened and issue on GitHub.

Comment: It *is* supported (as shown in the [`ssh2-streams` documentation](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams#ssh2stream-methods)), it's just not in the default list for security reasons. My example shows you how to add it, just set an explicit list with whatever ciphers you require. Order matters also.

Comment: Thanks! I'd been searching a couple of hours, finally I realized its a cipher mismatch and then I found your post. This helped me connect to my Cisco Router.